# Equation of the line, vertical

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the equation of the line, so I want to use y-y1=m(x-x1)  but for a vertical line the slope is undefined.  So I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:  there is one thing in common among the coordinates of all of the points on a vertical line.  Express this common feature as an equation an you'll have the equation of your line.

Comment: the common feature is where it hits x?  I don't know how to find that in y-(-4)=?(x-5)  what do I do with the undefined number?  Ignore it? and use it as x-5? or do i assign it a n and do n(x-5)?  I am sure it's evident my math skills aren't very advanced but I want to understand the concept.

Comment: You must read and interpret mathematics very carefully to succeed, especially once you hit algebra.  "Where it hits x" should be "where it hits the x-axis", since the x-axis is the visual object that your line can hit.  This place where it hits would be a point.  If you read carefully what I wrote, I said that the common feature is among the COORDINATES of the points on the line.  It might help to draw axes and label them with some coordinates, draw a vertical line, pick a few points on it and write down their coordinates.  You will notice a pattern in their x-coordinates when you do this.

Answer (score 5):

A vertical line in the plane is defined by the equation $x = c$, where $c$ is some real. This makes sense because along the vertical line, the $x$ value doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of it using the slightly massaged one:

dx*(y-b) = dy*(x-a)

for the line passing through (a,b) and "having slope" dy/dx  (here dx = 0 )

Answer (score 0):

use the equation of a line: $ax+by+c=0$

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is tagged as linear algebra:

You might be interested in expressing your line using a parametric equation involving vectors.

For example, if you want a vertical line (in the direction of the standard basis vector $(0,1)$) which passes through the point $(3,7)$, then you could use
$$(x,y)=(3,7)+t\cdot (0,1)$$
where $t$ varies over all scalars (elements of $\mathbb{R}$ probably).

In this particular case of a vertical line, as others have noted, the equation would be equivalent to just writing $$x=3+t\cdot 0=3$$ since the $x$ value does not vary, and the $y$ value is not constrained.

More generally, the equation for the line in the direction of vector $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$ and passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ would be
$$(x,y) = (x_0,y_0) + t\cdot (\Delta x,\Delta y)$$

You should understand this as an equation which describes the collection of points which includes $(x_0, y_0)$, along with any point we get by starting at $(x_0, y_0)$ and moving some distance (forward or backward) in the direction of $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$.  If you think about this a bit, you should see that this has the advantage of generalizing fairly easily to higher dimensional spaces, where you've got more variables than just $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score -1):

How about below parameterization.

$ \rho = x \cos{\theta} + y \sin{\theta}$

where

$ \rho $ = perpendicular distance to the line from the origin (0,0)

$ \theta $ = angle of a line perpendicular to our line with the x axis

you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform.

when line slope is $90^o$, $\theta = 0^o$, then $ \rho = x $.

Comment: when line slope is $0^o$, $\theta  = 90^o$ and $\rho = y$.